# MYSQL: Update value from Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've got a query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.products_id,a.zenid 
FROM titles a, ANOTHERDATABASE.products_description b
WHERE b.products_name = a.title
```

It gives

```
id  products_id     zenid
57  3193        0
81  2037        0
```

What i really need is to update zendid with products_id so it becomes:

```
id  products_id     zenid
57  3193        3193
81  2037        2037
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you are updating a table using a join in MySQL:

```
UPDATE titles a
  INNER JOIN ANOTHERDATABASE.products_description b
    ON b.products_name = a.title
SET a.zenid = b.products_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update a
set a.zenid=b.products_id
from titles a inner join ANOTHERDATABASE.products_description b 
on b.products_name = a.title
```