# Update row with self reference in a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I have a table with about 7000 rows where about 4000 have an error caused of a bug. (The location is `'null'` **not** `NULL` and should be somthing else.) Now I'm trying to fix the data which is for almost all rows possible.

```
UPDATE `timelog` t
SET `location`=(SELECT location
                FROM timelog tl
                WHERE tl.end_ts=t.end_ts AND location != 'null'
                ORDER BY tl.log_id DESC
                LIMIT 0,1) -- Just to make sure that I get 1 or 0 results
WHERE end_ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND location = 'null';
```

But I get the error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Well it seems that I cannot access the row itself while updating how can I slove that problem?

Maybe with a temp table, but that seems to be a little overhead also I have to manage to copy all unrelated rows too.

I also tried to use instat a join like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148180/995926), but I need to restrict the selected row.

---

Based on the answers I tried my own solution with a temp view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW right_locations AS
SELECT l.*, t.end_ts, t.location, (SELECT location FROM timelog tl WHERE tl.end_ts=t.end_ts AND location != 'null' ORDER BY tl.log_id DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS "possible", t.end_location
FROM `log` l
JOIN timelog t ON t.log_id=l.log_id
WHERE l.action_id =7 AND l.ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY end_location;

UPDATE timelog t
JOIN right_locations r ON r.log_id=t.log_id
SET t.location = r.possible
WHERE t.end_ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND t.location = 'null';
```

Comment: Why are you using a view instead of straight forward joins?

Comment: My tries with a join didn't work. My Triest working solution is above.

Comment: Did you try my solution using the left join to get the max value? It should produce exactly the same result as your version with the view?

Comment: Right now I'm working on a report and have no time to recover the data from a dump and replay the update. I'll try that in a view days and will inform you if your statement works correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work that much with mysql, but you can try to create a view with the subquery and then use that view.

```
create view timelogView
(
SELECT location
FROM timelog tl
WHERE tl.end_ts=t.end_ts AND location != 'null'
ORDER BY tl.log_id DESC
LIMIT 0,1
)

UPDATE `timelog` t
SET `location`=(SELECT location
                FROM timelogView tl) -- Just to make sure that I get 1 or 0 results
WHERE end_ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND location = 'null';
```

let me know if that works :)

Comment: Thank your for your answer. But without testing this won't work, the table `t` is unknown in the view definition. But i may be able to "join" that condition... brb

Comment: yes, the condition tl.end_ts=t.end_ts shouldn't be in the view and you don't need the order by since you don't want to display the result of the select.

Comment: try this: 
create view timelogView
(
SELECT location
FROM timelog tl
)

UPDATE `timelog` t
SET `location`=(SELECT location
                FROM timelogView where location != 'null') tl
WHERE t.end_ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND tl.end_ts=t.end_ts AND t.location = 'null';

Comment: No that won't work too. Your view makes no sense. I need the time informations for the update. Also you should better update your answer that makes i easier to read.

Comment: Well your answer is buggy but your idea with the view was good! I'll accept your answer.

Comment: thanks, maybe a little more experience on mysql would have improved my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

the solution I found sounds interessting. Maybe you'll give it a try?

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/

```
UPDATE timelog t
SET location = (
  select location from (
    SELECT tl.location
    FROM timelog tl
    WHERE tl.end_ts = t.end_ts AND tl.location != 'null'
    ORDER BY tl.log_id DESC
    LIMIT 1
 ) as x
WHERE 
  t.end_ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND 
  t.location = 'null';
```

something like that?

Comment: I have this page curriently opened before asking the question. I'm not sure how to use this in my case.

Comment: That looks got but does not work: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10*

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following -

```
UPDATE timelog t1
INNER JOIN timelog t2
    ON t1.end_ts = t2.end_ts
    AND t2.location != 'null'
LEFT JOIN timelog t3
    ON t2.end_ts = t3.end_ts
    AND t3.location != 'null'
    AND t2.log_id < t3.log_id
SET t1.location = t2.location
WHERE t1.end_ts > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
AND t1.location = 'null'
AND t3.log_id IS NULL;
```

**EDIT** Added LEFT JOIN to force update with latest value from t2 that matches the join criteria (same effect as order by id DESC LIMIT 1).

Comment: The log_id is my primary key and cannot be `NULL`. The main part could work.

Comment: The idea of the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` in this case is to find the record that does not have a match with a higher id, hence the `t3.log_id IS NULL`